# Transferring images to/from Android App through Cloud Endpoints to App Engine back-end

Tags: android, image, google-app-engine, upload

I'm currently working on an app that requires images to be passed to and from an App engine back-end. Originally I planned on sending the images (they are only small - max 100kb - average 20kb) directly through the endpoint however when sending the data as a byte array through the endpoint I receive a JSON error (from the rest API) stating that the data has an invalid character. Is there a way around this?

My second attempt was to use use the BlobService and return an upload URL to the client using the below code:

```
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
UploadOptions uploadOptions = UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName("bucketname").maxUploadSizeBytes(1048576);              
String url = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/uploaded", uploadOptions);
```

Then using a HTTP post on the android device to upload the image:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addPart("data", new ByteArrayBody(data,"image/png","img.png"));
httppost.setEntity(entity);
String res = EntityUtils.toString( httpclient.execute(httppost).getEntity(), "UTF-8");
```

This seems to work and the image is uploaded. However, I have no idea how to get the blobkey of this uploaded image. Does anyone know? Also, the result from the HTTP post is a 404 error - because the "/uploaded" page does not exist I'm guessing?

Thirdly, when manually typing in the blobkey and using it to return and image serving url with this code:

```
    private String getImage(){
        return getThumbUrl(new BlobKey("encoded_gs_key:ZGNpbWcxMy93czZwZ2lUeXdpY0xvZ2xtZGpHZ2dn")); 
    }

    private String getThumbUrl(BlobKey blobkey){       
        ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobkey);
        try {
            return ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService().getServingUrl(options);
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch(ImagesServiceFailureException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I receive the URL of the image however the image colors are all messed up. I am uploading indexed pngs... I'm not sure if the ImageService can handle them correctly. If it cant, how do I go about serving the image directly i.e. not through the ImageService but through BlobstoreService.serve()?

Here is an image of the resultant picture from the ImageService URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc500.png

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: Where do you want to get the blob key? Configure the blobstore upload url so that it calls back your appengine, there it will get the key.

Answer (score 0):

About the blob key, when you create the upload url you pass a paramenter with the name of your appengine page that gets called after upload. You need to implement that page ("uploaded") https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob